# Complexity of checking whether a BigInteger is a perfect square

Tags: java, biginteger

In the program I am writing, I have used the following method to check whether a number is a perfect square or not.

```
// Checks whether x is a perfect square
public static boolean issqr(BigInteger x){
    a=x.sqrt();
    return x.equals(a.multiply(a));
}
```

In the above code, the following methods from the BigInteger class are used :-

- BigInteger multiply(BigInteger num) : Returns the product of this and num.
- boolean equals(object obj) : Checks for equality between this and obj.
- BigInteger sqrt() : Returns the integral part of the square root of this.

I believe that the sqrt() method in Java uses Newton's method, which would model a binary search algorithm. The issqr(BigInteger x) method above must have the same complexity as the sqrt() method in BigInteger class. However, on comparing the run times for different values of x in the issqr(BigInteger x) method, it looks as though the run time is growing exponentially instead.

What is the reason for a binary search algorithm to have exponential run time complexity? Does it have anything to do with memory and the immutability of BigInteger datatype? Is there a more efficient algorithm to check if a number is a perfect square? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Multiplication is *O(N**2)* ...

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/9709

Comment: @MarquisofLorne - Actually, no it isn't; see the link above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR - it is complicated!

---

According to Emil Jeřábek in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/9709

> The square root of an N-digit number can be computed in time `O(M(n))` using e.g. Newton’s iteration, where `M(N)` is the time needed to multiply two N-digit integers. The current best bound on `M(n)` is `N logN 2^O(logN)` using [Fürer’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm).

So the theoretical complexity of the complete check would be `O(M(N)) + O(M(N/2))` which reduces to `O(M(N))`.

---

In practice, we need to look at how `BigInteger` is implemented.  According to comments in the Java 11 source code

> "The implementation [of `MutableBigInteger.sqrt()`] is based on the material in Henry S. Warren, Jr., *Hacker's Delight (2nd ed.)* (Addison Wesley, 2013), 279-282.

According to the source code, Java 11 `BigInteger.multiply(BigInteger)` implementation uses:

- a naive "grade school" algorithm for small numbers,
- the [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), for intermediate numbers, or
- an "optimal" 3-way Toom-Cook algorithm for really large numbers.

The latter is described in *Towards Optimal Toom-Cook Multiplication for Univariate and Multivariate Polynomials in Characteristic 2 and 0.* by Marco BODRATO; In C.Carlet and B.Sunar, Eds., "WAIFI'07 proceedings".

I don't have access to the references to check what they  say about the complexity of 3-way Toom-Cook or Warren's algorithm respectively.  However, Wikipedia says that Karatsuba multiplication for N-digit numbers has an asymptotic bound of `Θ(N**log2(3))`.

Based on that, we can say that checking if an N-digit number is a perfect square using `BigInteger` is *likely* to be `O(N**log2(3))` == `O(N**~1.585)` *or better*.

Comment: It seems like you are neglecting the cost of the sqrt() algorithm, although you do mention it. I would guess it takes at least log(log(n)) multiplies (assuming we count a division as the same cost as a multiply).

Comment: No I didn't.  Assuming that Emil Jeřábek is correct it is `O(M(N))`, and `M(N)` is `O(N**~1.585)` or better for `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that, it's right at the beginning of your answer :) As for Jeřábek's claim, he seems to know what he's saying but includes no reference nor analysis to back up his claim. Perhaps we just throw away log(log(N)), since it so small for any computation we can actually perform on a real computer and so flat over such a huge range it is effectively a constant.